# how to add identity user from another project in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I have .net web api project which uses identity to store users. I have another admin web application project seperate from api. My question is how can I add users from my admin project. Probably I need to add user with UserManager instead of adding user via Entity Framework. But how to do that? How can I use another project's UserManager from my admin web project? or what is proper way to add user from another project?

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding your first project to other like multi layer project. If i were you, i would create a new layer and add it to my second project. Also i suggest  you can check identity framework.

Comment: I think I will store users added from admin in another table than identity user table , then when they trying to login in my api I will get user from that temp table and create identity user with user manager. This will cost redundant user table buy I don t know how to solve problem without this extra user table

Comment: It will work but  slow your program. You should check the how identity framework works, and you should probably start a new project and join two programs.

Comment: I am not going to create new project, my project is existing project. Btw I m not talking about different layers, they different projects. Admin project is different repo and have different application on iis and web api different repo and have own application on iis